# How to receive "output" variable of SP in SSIS to count how many data entered into conditional IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I have an SQL Procedure like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExampleSP]
    @ID int,
    @name varchar(30),
    @Counter int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    ---- ********************************************************************************************************
    if (@name is not null)
    BEGIN
        update People
        set name = @name
        where Id = @ID
    END

    set @Counter = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

What I want is here to count how many rows entered the if condition!

In SSIS -> I have a common variable, called RecordCounter = 0 by default.

I have a Data Flow Task in my Control Flow.

In the Data Flow: -> I have a Flat File Source, reading data from a .dat file.

Example data in the file:

```
ID|NAME
1  Jack
2  
3  Mike
```

Then, I have Derived Column, adding RecordCounter as a column to the data.

```
RecordCounter <add as new column> @[User::RecordCounter] four-byte signed integer [DT_I4]
```

Then, I have OLE DB Command, which enables the data goes row by row to my SP. SQL Command for that is:

```
EXEC [dbo].[ProcessClientRegistryRecord] ?,?,? OUTPUT
```

And finally, I have a Row Count item, mapping the variable User::RecordCounter

Here is the figure:

[image]

When I run this, the RecordCounter is showing the number of total data in my file, instead how many of them went into the IF block in the StoredProcedure. It should return 2 in this situation for example, not 3. Where is my mistake, how should I fix it? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how do you calculate the value of `@Counter` variable  ?

Comment: In the SP? It is increasing one by one when a data goes to if condition?

Comment: Yes I can see this, but what value is passed to the procedure's `@Counter` variable and where does it come from?

Comment: In the Column Mappings section of OLE DB Command, RecordCounter is mapping to "@Counter". So I am expecting to have the value of RecordCounter SSIS variable as the value of "@Counter"

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, you are not actually passing any value to the output parameter but expecting an output value, a number of rows affected by the update statement ?

Comment: You might be right. But I dont know how to fix this situation. Can you help me on this?

Comment: EXEC [dbo].[ProcessClientRegistryRecord] ?,?,? OUTPUT   Here the last ? is supposed to belong to RecordCounter variables?

Answer (score 0):

After some explanation from you I think I know where you are going wrong.

I think you have done everything right except the logic in the stored procedure.

Your Stored procedure should look like....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExampleSP]
    @ID int,
    @name varchar(30),
    @Counter int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 IF (@name is not null)
  BEGIN

    update People
    set name = @name
    where Id = @ID

    SET @Counter = @@ROWCOUNT;  

  END
END
```

Finally in your SSIS package you can add an aggregate task to sum all the rows update from the derived column. You package should look something like...

[image]

In the `OLE DB Transformation` on the `Component Properties` tab should have the call to stored procedure as

```
Exec [dbo].[ExampleSP] ? , ? , ? OUTPUT
```

And finally on the `Column Mapping` tab, the OUTPUT parameter should be mapped to your derived column:

[image]

Comment: The if condition is important here, I only need the total number of data entered inside the if condition. I would like to send RecordCounter variable as a parameter to the SP, and save the returned @Counter value as the new value of RecordCounter, then send the new value in my next loop (recursively)

Comment: Edited a few things in my question for u to better understand.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli there is `NO` looping here. Your `@Counter` variable is always null, unless you pass a value to it at the time you are executing it. The update statement works with sets, it will update whatever the number of records it will find for the value passed in the ID variable and `@@ROWCOUNT` function will give you the number of records it will update.

Comment: There's no need to aggregate. Just use `SET @Counter += @@ROWCOUNT;` to add to the previous value.

Comment: OLE DB Command is using Exec [dbo].[ExampleSP] ? , ? , ? OUTPUT and the mapping is like exactly you have shown to me. I am trying to change SP now, will let u know the result.

Comment: @MartinSmith the procedure is being called for each row. On next call to the procedure `@Counter` will be null.

Comment: I dont understand why you removed IF condition in the SP but? I need to check if @name is null or not?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli yes you can add the if statement to check other stuff but not the `@Counter` variable, it will always be null in this case.

Comment: how come @@RowCount; can return me 2 in the end? There will be 3 records will come to SP from the file read by SSIS?

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought it would work like the execute SQL task and assign the output param back into an ssis variable but doesn't look like it works that way...

Comment: Do you already have all three IDs in the table? mind you this procedure only updates record so only the ID that already exists in the table will be updated.

Comment: Yes I do have all IDs in the table. Just the ones who comes with `not null` name value from SSIS should be updated only. And those updates would be counted

Comment: @MartinSmith this is `OLE DB Command` transformation runs inside a data flow task i.e once for each row , unlike `Execute SQL` task which is a control flow task runs once unless used inside a foeach loop.

Comment: Should I select only name in the "group by" in SSIS, right?

Comment: Yes, I know. But if it assigned the value of the output param back into the SSIS variable (which it doesn't so hypothetical anyway) then on the next call for the next row the accumulated value so far would be passed in to the output parameter and added to.

Comment: When I select only name, it is returning 2, so it is true. But wanna make sure something that: Is it counting "JACK" and "MIKE" and not counting the null value in the groupby then, right?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli `Group By` for Aggregate ? if so , you dont need to group by anything, if you just want to get the total number of rows updated, Also do you know something called `Data Viewer`? enable that and you can see the actual data flowing throwing pipes.

Comment: Aggregate pushes me select one attribute to count and one attribute (at least) to group by. It doesnt let me just pull and put an Aggregate, connect it to the figure and run the application. (I dont know Data Viewer)

Comment: Sorry, it is possible not to select any attribute as group by, but in this case RecordCounter is returning 1, not 2

Comment: I believe aggregate is not specifically counting how many records went into IF condition. It seems like it is grouping the data by name and returning total number of groups.

Comment: In the `aggregate` transformation, just select the `Derived column` as your `INPUT column`,  The column you mapped to OUTPUT parameter in the OLE DB transformation, In `operation` select `SUM` and leave  the group by empty.

Comment: The SP is exactly what you provided now. Aggregate has only one attribute, the one I derived to map to output parameter and operation is SUM. Still returning 1 instead 2. :(

Comment: Just a note, making set @Counter += @@ROWCOUNT doesnt change the result, still 1.

Comment: I believe the counter value is not getting updated after each loop, the SSIS variable RecordCounter should be updated after each data going into the IF. Still it is not provided somehow here, right? :(

Comment: The default value of RecordCounter SSIS variable is 0, so 0 is going to the SP for each data. We should manage to update it. It is linked to @Counter int OUTPUT variable in SSIS. Why it is not getting updated you think?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning value out of the context seems not to work at least you do a final assignment.

```
**Declare  @Id int =?, @rowCount int =?;
EXEC Exec [dbo].[ExampleSP]   @Id , @rowCount  OUTPUT;
SELECT ? = @rowCount;**
```

Also, be aware of mapping starts at 0.